# Bootstrap toggle button does not work when I put an image at down

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new on web design and I'm trying to use bootstrap toggle button, but it does not works when I put an image at down, I supose that the content is displaying at back of that Image.

This is the css and html, you can run code snipet to see what happens.

```css
.mynavbar{
 height: 83px !important;
 font-family: 'Raleway',verdana !important;
 background: rgb(238,238,238) !important;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.mynavbar>.container-fluid>.navbar-collapse>ul{
 margin-top: 15px;
}

.mynavbar>.container-fluid>.navbar-header>div>.navbar-brand{
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.blabla{
 position: relative;
 font-family: 'Old Standard TT',serif;
}

.inner {
 text-align: center;
 color:white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>Hi</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>


</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default mynavbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#togglebutton">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="vRef">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company Name</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="togglebutton">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Us </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login </a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Service <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="blabla">
      <img src="http://static.panoramio.com/photos/original/182912.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="website template image">
      <div class="inner"><h1>My Company Name</h1><br/><h4>Some thing about m company</h4></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I know that something in css code is wrong, just when I'm centering the text with .blabla and .inner classes. But I need that and I dont know how to do that without killing toggle button function.

Any orientation?

Sorry for my bad english and thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you cant see your toggled menu is you are forcing the height of your navbar using `height: 83px !important;` the navigation toggle actually makes the height larger to show the hidden elements.

change the code for `.mynavbar` to use `min-height: 83px;` instead of the `!important` style

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tht41zwn/)**

Answer (score 1):

You defined fixed height for `.mynavbar`. You need to remove that and make `margin-bottom: 0 !important` to remove a gap between menu and image. And to make a view as you need, you can add `padding-bottom: 20px;`.

Look at snippet

```css
.mynavbar{
 font-family: 'Raleway',verdana !important;
 background: rgb(238,238,238) !important;
 margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.mynavbar>.container-fluid>.navbar-collapse>ul{
 margin-top: 15px;
}

.mynavbar>.container-fluid>.navbar-header>div>.navbar-brand{
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.blabla{
 position: relative;
 font-family: 'Old Standard TT',serif;
}

.inner {
 text-align: center;
 color:white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>Hi</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>


</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default mynavbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#togglebutton">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="vRef">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company Name</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="togglebutton">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Us </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login </a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Service <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="blabla">
      <img src="http://static.panoramio.com/photos/original/182912.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="website template image">
      <div class="inner"><h1>My Company Name</h1><br/><h4>Some thing about m company</h4></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Another way, if you don't want to change height of menu, is to add `z-index: -1;` to `.blabla` class, but then you need to add background to submenu

```css
.mynavbar{
 height: 83px !important;
 font-family: 'Raleway',verdana !important;
 background: rgb(238,238,238) !important;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.mynavbar>.container-fluid>.navbar-collapse>ul{
 margin-top: 15px;
 background: rgb(238,238,238) !important;
}

.mynavbar>.container-fluid>.navbar-header>div>.navbar-brand{
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.blabla{
 position: relative;
 font-family: 'Old Standard TT',serif;
  z-index: -1;
}

.inner {
 text-align: center;
 color:white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>Hi</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>


</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default mynavbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#togglebutton">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="vRef">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company Name</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="togglebutton">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Us </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login </a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Service <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="blabla">
      <img src="http://static.panoramio.com/photos/original/182912.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="website template image">
      <div class="inner"><h1>My Company Name</h1><br/><h4>Some thing about m company</h4></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you meant, that the menu is not visible, add z-index to .mynavbar and make this class as relative position. Check this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/muhsin84/tbsmyo99/9/)**

```
.mynavbar{
    height: 83px !important;
    font-family: 'Raleway',verdana !important;
    background: rgb(238,238,238) !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css change:

```
.inner {
Text-align: center;
Color:white;
    Position: absolute;
    Left: 50%;
    Top: 50%;
    Transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

To

```
.inner {
Text-align: center;
Color:white;
    Position: absolute;
    Left: 50%;
    Top: 50%;
    Margin-right: -50%
    Transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

You need the margin-right to compensate for the margin left and also benefical as it makes your div responsive

Comment: If my answer helped you please accept it :) happy coding

Comment: i think the main question OP is asking about is the toggle button, not the centering of the text. PS. CSS definitions should be lowercase, and the block element `.inner` doesnt need the 100% width to be centered :)

Comment: They specifically said they were having problems centering text "I know that something in css code is wrong, just when I'm centering the text with .blabla and .inner classes."

Comment: the name of the question is about the bootstrap toggle button :) the text is already centered, your solution makes no difference to the toggle button, or the centering of the text